# Identityserver3 - Select Identityprovider a client should use

Tags: identityserver3, oidc-client-js

I now have identityserver3 setup, i have 3 identityproviders configured:
 - Local 
 - Google
 - ADFS

I have multiple clients using Oidc-Client-JS (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js).

Now i would like to specify which identityprovider a client should use to login. so lets say:

- Client A lets the user choose which provider to use
- Client B logs in with local
- Client C logs in with google
- Client D logs in with ADFS

The situation of Client A is the default behavior and i have that working. My question is how do i set up clients B,C and D?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following function in your start up see what you called your Identityprovider in my case "Google".

```
    public static void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Google",
```

In your client set the acr_value for idp to what ever you have set.

```
    let userManagerSettings: Oidc.UserManagerSettings = {
        acr_values: "idp:Google",
```

Now the client will automatically redirect to the correct identityprovider

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IdentityServer3 documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html), you need to configure the IdentityProviderRestrictions for each clients. In case of only one identity provider is configured, the IdSrv3 will automatically redirect.